# cannot import name 'external_account_authorized_user' from 'google.auth'

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-python-client

```
from pprint import pprint
from Goo_gle import Create_Service


CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'Client_Calendar.json'
API_NAME = 'calendar'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth']


service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\Play with code\PROGRAMMINGS\Python\Artificial Inteligence\calen_dar.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Goo_gle import Create_Service   File "d:\Play with code\PROGRAMMINGS\Python\Artificial Inteligence\Goo_gle.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .interactive import get_user_credentials   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\interactive.py", line 27, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 69, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.helpers   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\helpers.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.auth import external_account_authorized_user ImportError: cannot import name 'external_account_authorized_user' from 'google.auth' (C:\Python\lib\site-packages\google\auth\__init__.py)
```

I am not getting why this is happening.
This code was working from last 3 month but today after updating google libraries, this error came.. How to fix this?

Comment: what is Create_Service?  Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I am also getting the same error. I think it has something to do with the [google-auth-oauthlib==0.6.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-auth-oauthlib/0.6.0/) released yesterday.  I will try reverting back of 0.5.3

Answer (score 13):

Looks to be related to a recent change in the `google-auth-library-python-oauth` module:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/pull/240/files#diff-63cdf7d9059947cf2f03b72a8137b8a1901de52f685705c251886d58a75b9381L8

Upgrading google-auth to 2.13.0 may fix it.

Comment: This upgrade fixed my problem.

Comment: Upgrading is not a good idea, it will take effort to verify the app before the deployment.

Answer (score 9):

You will get that error when using `google_auth_oauthlib` as the latest version (0.6.0). Refer to this link: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/blob/v0.6.0/google_auth_oauthlib/helpers.py#L27

Try to downgrade google-auth-oauthlib lib by using this command:
`pip install google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6`

or update your requirement.txt to add this line:

```
...
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
...
```

Comment: I am using pydata-google-auth, what should i do?

Comment: @shzyincu You can see `pydata-google-auth` is using `google-auth-oauthlib` as the latest version here https://github.com/pydata/pydata-google-auth/blob/main/requirements.txt. You just need to update your `requirements.txt` file to add `google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6` to override it.

Comment: For Ubuntu users (Python 3.8) using h5pyd, this is the appropriate fix when encountering this error

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade google-auth-oauthlib==0.6.0 (released yesterday) to 0.5.3 has solved my problem.
Thank's to @Samik

Comment: I am with 0.5.3 and it is still falling.